# Creating tooltip in Compact Framework

Tags: c#, compact-framework, tooltip

I'm trying to create tooltips for form elements (textboxes, etc) in WinCE 5.0 using the Compact Framework 3.5. I believe the functionality is implemented in the OS but not exposed in the managed framework. Any way to create this functionality with P/Invokes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MSDN covers it fairly thoroughly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms927173.aspx) for native code.  You can obviously P/Invoke CreateWindowEx and SHInitExtraControls.  From that point on, it's all about using the [tool tip messages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452789.aspx) like TTM_ACTIVATE to control the tip.

It's all very doable, but just looking at the API, I'd guesstimate it's probably a week of work to churn out a managed object model for it.

Comment: I did see this article but don't know native code well enough to go far with it. Also i don't have a week to kill on UI niceties. Thanks for the input though.